# What language would be appropriate for texts to be written in about Thor (Forgotten Realms)?

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, religions-and-deities, languages

In our LMoP campaign, there is a Cleric whose deity is Thor. He has come across several texts that discuss Thor (myths and religious texts).

What language would those texts most likely be written in?

(I don't know if this is helpful context, but he is a Wood Elf).

Would Illuski (Nordic) languages be appropriate here?

Comment: Done - yes, trying to fit Thor ir given that Ysgard still presumably exists as another plane.

Comment: Do you know who wrote the texts?

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir Very open, could be anything from lowly Thor cultists to disciples who traveled from Ysgard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Thor is not a member of any of the official pantheons of the Forgotten Realms, the answer to this question is best left to the DM. Here are some relevant options described in the 2e Forgotten Realms sourcebook *Giantcraft*:

- Thorass: the old form of common. It has some common roots with Jotun.
- Jotun: the language of the giants. Written in the runic script Dethek, it is similar to Scandinavian languages according to the [FR wiki](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Giant_language). (Thor's myth involves his many dealings with giants.)
- Jotunalder: An ancient form of Jotun, usually used in giant clerical rites.

Another alternative could be Celestial, the language of the beings from the Upper Planes (presumably including Ysgard).